# How to correctly save images to the filesystem with fs.writeFile?

Tags: node.js, express, formidable

I can't figure out how i can correctly save a file i got from formidable to the file system my server is running on.

I am able to console.log the files, however i do not know what to do with the information provided there.

```
app.post("/sendImages", (req, res) => {
  const files = req.files;
  Object.keys(files).forEach((key) => {
    console.log(files[key]);
    fs.writeFile('images/' + files[key].name, files[key], 'binary', (error) => {
      if (error) console.log(error);
      else console.log('image created');
    });
  })
});
```

This request handler right here creates files with the correct names, but when i try to open them in VS Code the only thing i see is [object Object].

An example of a console logged file:

```
File {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  size: 3835864,
  path:
   'C:\\Users\\MY_USER_DIR\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\upload_b099c61751b3b25772344e20df06a4d9',
  name: '20190602_134136.jpg',
  type: 'image/jpeg',
  hash: null,
  lastModifiedDate: 2019-06-30T15:03:22.060Z,
  _writeStream:
   WriteStream {
     _writableState:
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        finalCalled: true,
        needDrain: true,
        ending: true,
        ended: true,
        finished: true,
        destroyed: true,
        decodeStrings: true,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: true,
        errorEmitted: false,
        emitClose: false,
        autoDestroy: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: false,
     _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
     _eventsCount: 0,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     path:
      'C:\\Users\\MY_USER_DIR\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\upload_b099c61751b3b25772344e20df06a4d9',
     fd: null,
     flags: 'w',
     mode: 438,
     start: undefined,
     autoClose: true,
     pos: undefined,
     bytesWritten: 3835864,
     closed: false } }
```

I hope someone of you can tell me what i did wrong here, i am new to node in general and still have some problems here and there :)

Comment: Don't roll your own code for what already exists in an unreasonably large ecosystem of available code. If you're using Express, have a look at https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.properties which explains `req.files` is no longer supported, and gives you quite a few excellent options for handling file uploads of quite a few different kinds.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I am using express-formidable, which adds the req.files back. This still doesn't get me further as the problem lies in saving the files, not receiving them.

Comment: I don't understand, the https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable documentation shows how to save files as its very first code example, and your code does not look like their example - either you didn't read the documentation, or you're not working with data that gets posted to your server by using `<form>` file inputs, in which case formidable is 100% useless since it's specifically _only_ for form data, and you'll want to use a different library entirely.

Comment: I use [express-formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-formidable), which basically does the same as formidable.

Again, my problem isn't receiving the images, it is writing them to the file system. The files get created in the 'images'-folder but i can't open them because the only thing that gets stored in them is [object Object].

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans So i just found out that i can rename the files stored in the temp-folder to .jpg and then i can open them just like any other .jpg file. So it must be the `fs.writeFile(...)` that is not working as i expect it to.

Comment: Protip: if you're not using the exact thing you're saying your using in your tags, *please put that information in your question*, because people can't look up what the functions and properties you rely on do if you don't explain exactly where they came from.

Answer (score 1):

You should copy files from tmp folder to images folder, like this (`Node.js >= 8.5.0`):

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');
const path = require('path');
const copyFile = util.promisify(fs.copyFile);

app.post('/sendImages', async (req, res) => {
  const files = req.files;
  const results = Object.keys(files).map((key) => {
    const file = files[key];
    const dest = path.join('images/', file.name);
    return copyFile(file.path, dest);
  });
  await Promise.all(results);
  // ...
});
```

And if you don't want to save files to tmp folder, you should check the api document for change the uploadDir. Like [express-formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-formidable):

```js
app.use(formidableMiddleware({
  encoding: 'utf-8',
  uploadDir: 'images/',
  multiples: true
});
```